# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0 The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just created a new project in Visual Studio using ASP.NET Framework 4.7.2, I created a brand new controller and tried to use HttpClient which is apart of System.Net.Http; But when I run my code I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The version of System.Net.Http I am using is 4.2.0.0 and I have no idea what I am doing wrong, everything I have seen all say to update my ASP.NET Framework to 4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded to 4.7.1 and now it works, go figure.